# How to plot line chart with multiple datas, but only 2 labels?

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js

So,

I've been using ng2-charts to so I can create components using the chartjs library in my angular application and I want to plot a chart that shows only the first and last label and point so the chart can be easy to read and clean.

How can I just show the first and last one?

Or only the last one

Answer (score 1):

In Chart.js the labels can be provided as an array.

Example

component.html

```
<canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
                    [datasets]="lineChartData"
                    [labels]="lineChartLabels"
                    chartType="line"></canvas>
```

component.ts

```
  public lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A' }
  ];
  public lineChartLabels: Label[] = ['January', '', '', '', '', '', 'July'];
```

As per your requirement, you can set empty values for labels except first and last one.